# Cannot locate my php ini file on live server?

Tags: php, cpanel

I tried different solutions suggested here, but still cannot find the file through cPanel on my live server.

I'm running

```
phpinfo();
```

And getting this result:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /opt/alt/php56/etc
```

I cannot find these folders: /opt/alt/php56
But I could find the etc folder, however the file is not there, and I made sure I checked "View hidden files" options

What else could be done?

Comment: you could try with the cli, `php -i | grep 'php.ini'` but it should be the same. Are you sur file are not in this directory ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

enter in your server comand line: `php -i` to see all of your php's config and also in very first lines of this command output, location of your php.ini if you can't find file like `php.ini` in your output which may not happen make one with `touch` command and put your configuration in that file and reload server, depend on what you use (like fpm or ...).

Answer (score 2):

Try this command and find the path of PHP

```
which php
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
php --ini
```

it will print all config files locations

Answer (score 1):

In WHM go to Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor and edit php.in for your PHP version.

OR edit: /usr/local/lib/php.ini